# Question about proof for recursive definitions (Terence Tao Analysis I)

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation

I'm confused by one remark in parentheses. I'm not sure why he had to invoke Axiom 2.3, and I think conceptually I don't get what he means by "redefine."

I'm also confused about his last remark about $a_{0.5}$.

First, here are the five Peano axioms he's using :

> **Axiom 2.1.** $0$ is a natural number.
>
> **Axiom 2.2.** If $n$ is a natural number, then $n{++}$ is also a natural number.
>
> **Axiom 2.3.** $0$ is not the successor of any natural number ; i.e., we have $n{++} \ne 0$ for every natural number $n$.
>
> **Axiom 2.4.** Different natural numbers must have different successors ; i.e., if $n, m$ are natural numbers and $n \ne m$, then $n{++} \ne m{++}$. Equivalently, if $n{++} = m{++}$, then we must have $n=m$.
>
> **Axiom 2.5.** (Principle of mathematical induction). Let $P(n)$ be any property pertaining to a natural number $n$. Suppose that $P(0)$ is true, and suppose that whenever $P(n)$ is true, $P(n{++})$ is also true. Then $P(n)$ is true for every natural number $n$.

And here is the proposition, and the proof (remark I'm unsure about bolded):

> **Proposition 2.1.16** (Recursive definitions). Suppose for each natural number $n$, we have some function $f_{n} : \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ from the natural numbers to the natural numbers. Let $c$ be a natural number. Then we can assign a unique natural number $a_{n}$ to each natural number $n$, such that $a_{0} = c$ and $a_{n{++}} = f_{n} (a_{n})$ for each natural number $n$.
>
> *Proof*. (Informal) We use induction. We first observe that this procedure gives a single value to $a_0$, namely $c$. (None of the other definitions $a_{n{++}}:= f_{n} (a_n)$ will **redefine** the value of $a_0$, because of Axiom 2.3.) Now suppose inductively that the procedure gives a single value to $a_n$. Then it gives a single value to $a_{n{++}}$, namely $a_{n{++}}:= f_{n} (a_n)$. (None of the other definitions $a_{m{++}}:= f_{m} (a_{m})$ will redefine the value of $a_{n{++}}$, because of Axiom 2.4.) This completes the induction, and so $a_n$ is defined for each natural number $n$, with a single value assigned to each $a_n$.
>
> Note how all the axioms had to be used here. In a system which had some sort of wrap-around, recursive definitions would not work because some elements of the sequence would constantly be redefined. For instance, in Example 2.1.5, in which $3++ = 0$ [A/N: Zmod3], then there would be (at least) two conflicting definitions for $a_0$, either $c$ or $f_3(a_3)).$ In a system which had superfluous elements such as $0.5$, the element $a_{0.5}$ would never be defined.

But,

1. How could defining $a_{n{++}}$ redefine the value of $a_0$? Isn't the definition of $a_{n++}$ providing a rule for constructing the next value in the sequence, rather than going back and pointing $a+0$ at another value? I would think that he meant to use the verb "return" instead of "redefine," but maybe I'm wrong.
2. If we decided to set c to any non-zero natural number, then we don't need to invoke Axiom 2.3, right? (Related question: His remark about Example 2.1.5 only holds if we set c to equal 0, right?)
3. I'm not sure why it is the case that element $a_{0.5}$ would never be defined. Previously, he states that induction should generally prevent fractions from appearing in N, so if N did not have fractions to begin with, they would never be at risk from being in the codomain for the given function (unless I misunderstood.)

Course notes [here](https://math.unm.edu/%7Ecrisp/courses/math401/tao.pdf).

Comment: For 1, you are presupposing that $0$ will never occur as the "next value" in the sequence. The author is calling out the importance of Axiom 2.3 in assuring that.

Comment: But I don't think it matters if 0 occurs as the next value in the sequence or not. My understanding is that we can still define a sequence (0,0,0) (imagine starting with c=0 and using the identity function for the next two terms) and that Tao asking $a_n$ to be unique rather refers to the fact that there can only be one possible value for **this slot** in the sequence, rather than unique from any other value in the sequence.

Comment: Actually, I think another poster previously answered (1) for me, but my questions about (2) and (3) remain:
(from Jessica:)
None of the other definitions $a_{n++}\colon=f_n(a_n)$ will redefine the value of $a_0$ because the way in which a natural number $a_n$ is assigned to another natural number $n$ is by the assignment $a_{n++}\colon=f_n(a_n)$ which involves the successor, and Axiom 2.3 tells us that $n++\neq0$ for every natural number $n$. Hence, it's impossible to define (again) $a_0$ once the procedure has begun.

Comment: For (2), I disagree.  The value of $c$ is largely insignificant, the argument is primarily about the subscript indices and not about the inputs or outputs of the functions.